# Automatic deobfuscation of Java class/method/parameter names with access to old non obfuscated sources

Tags: java, deobfuscation

I am currently trying to de-obfuscate a Java program (i.e. find each class name and namespace, each method name and each method parameter name).
To do so, I started by using Enigma (the fork from FabricMC).

But I have access to old sources that are **not** obfuscated and I was wondering if I could automatically de-obfuscate the part of my Java program that did not change since then.

Basically, I have:

- Version 3 that is non-obfuscated.
- Version 6 that is obfuscated.
- Version 7 that is obfuscated.
- Version 9 that is obfuscated.

and I want to de-obfuscate automatically as much symbols as possible in Version 9.

Are you aware of any tool that can do this? Currently, I am navigating the unobfuscated files of Version 3 by hand and mapping Version 9 on Enigma by hand too, which is quite a long and tedious process.

Note: all the subjects I found during my research were about de-obfuscating without access to any prior, non-obfuscated, sources. I would like to extract the maximum I can from the non-obfuscated sources I obtained.

Comment: An old release of skidsuite used to have something like this: https://github.com/GenericException/SkidSuite/tree/master/archive/skidsuite-2 (antiob package has CorrelationMapper). Can't say how well it works, never used it myself. But I would love to support a similar feature in my own project, Recaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried https://github.com/FabricMC/Matcher?
It doesn't always create the best matches automatically but it helps a lot by suggesting classes/methods/fields that are similar to each other across the different versions.

Comment: I do not know how I missed this tool, but it nicely answer my question! It lacks documentation though, but the community is super nice and very reactive on the FabricMC Discord!